# How to let user submit issue directly to Github

Tags: github, github-api, bug-tracking

I use github issues a lot. Is there any way that i could put a form of some sort on my Laravel project that a user can fill out and it will automatically submit an issue to Github? (without them going to github.com and having to sign in) I have looked for packages but can't find anything. The closest thing i could find was [this repo.](https://github.com/controlgroup/CSV-GitHub-import-export) Users could submit issues to a CSV file and occasionally i could export it to Github, but there has to be a better way. Anyone ever done this?

Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue -- You can just call the API from within your application. If this is the only endpoint you are going to hit, you will probably not need to use an API wrapper. The caveat being that it will be reported as created by the user the API key is for.

Comment: You won't be able to communicate with that user via Github. Initial bug reports rarely have all the information necessary, so the bug reports will be of limited use. You could include the user's email in the body of the bug report... but then you have to communicate with them privately via email defeating the point of using Github issues. You probably want to instead use an issue tracker that has email/automatic registration, or just submit the issues as yourself (or a 2nd account to make it clear this is via automation).

Comment: @Schwern That's a good point. I have emails stored for users in my application, so i could include their ID in the body and get their email that way if it comes to that. Thanks.